# How to get the properties group names in autodesk forge

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I would like to know is there any way to get the property group names in autodesk forge. I have tried with `getProperties()` and `getBulkProperties()` but I cant get the group names. How to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

[image: I need to get only the highlighted group names]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property group is not named as `group` in the Forge viewer. It's called `category` in this case, and can be accessed via the `displayCategory`. Here is an example:

```
var selection = viewer.getSelection();
viewer.getProperties( selection[0], function( result ) {
    const props = result.properties;
    for( let i = 0; i < props .length; i++ ) {
        const property = props[i];
        if( property.hidden) return;

        const category = props[i].displayCategory;
        if( category && typeof category === 'string' && category !== '' ) {
            // The property group you want
            console.log( category );
        }
    }
});
```

BTW, you can see more detail from this blog:https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/adding-custom-meta-properties-to-the-viewer-property-panel.html

Hope this help.